# UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath) always return No

Tags: ios, objective-c

if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath))     {
                                              UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(filePath, self,  @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
                                                                                    }

Printing description of filePath:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F30CE4FC-435B-414E-BD79-27BA9CE8F4A9/Documents/NORM0078.MP4

How can I resolve it? Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: The video file is absoluted existed through checked.

Answer (score 0):

AllRight, I have find the solution. The video type is not supported to be played with Quickplayer(The default player for iphone),So the video can't be saved to system album.